# Why is there a huge gap between my content and my footer?

Tags: html, css, footer

I have 2 columns on the page which are floated to the left, and contained in a wrapper div called 'content'.

I then have a footer contained in #footer. There is a huge gap between my content and footer, and I cannot figure out why! Here's the link to the codepen and the relevant code:

http://codepen.io/Pea92/pen/WvrXRY

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="sidebar">Information etc</div>
<div class="column2"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
float:left:
width:20%;
}
.column2 {
float:left;
width:60%;
}
```

Comment: Huge gap? How huge and where? Can you point it out?

Comment: CSS property `column-count` is the culprit here. Not sure why its leaving extra space. `column-count:2` or 4 seems better

Comment: Hmm yeah I just noticed that too. Really want it to be 3 columns though! No idea why it's doing this...

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error:

```
<div class="clear" <div="" id="footer">
        <p>© Copyright 2015</p>

    </div>
```

You did not close your `<div` tags... please always validate your code. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Hi, thanks. I closed the div, but it still isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the closing > to your clear div. Or anyways, there's something wrong with the code at the bottom of your page. There's something missing, correct your code.

```
<div class="clear"
      <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy; Copyright 2015</p>

    </div>


  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I closed the div, but it still isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug, there is something wrong with the balancing algorithm of the multicol layout: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297782